# Accessing 'this' function from within the same function

Tags: javascript

I wrote some javascript to simulate a namespace.  The following global allows me to access the **get_cp_span()** getter method from other namespaces:

```
var my_ns;  // global access

$(document).ready(function() {
  my_ns = new my_namespace();   // need global access to my_ns
});

function my_namespace() {
  var cp_span = $("#cp_span");

  // public getter  
  this.get_cp_span = function() {
    return cp_span;
  }

  var do_something = function() {
    //get_cp_span().hide();         // ReferenceError: get_cp_span is not defined
    //this.get_cp_span().hide();    // TypeError: this.get_cp_span is not a function
    my_ns.get_cp_span().hide(); // works
  }
};
```

I thought that I would be able to easily access my public getter **cp_span()** from within the my_namespace() by calling **this.get_cp_span()** or by just calling **get_cp_span()** but it only works when I call **my_ns.get_cp_span()** which is how I would call it from a different 'namespace'.

In order for me to access get_cp_span() from within the same function, I have to refer to the global variable.

Comment: Did you try `cp_span.hide()`?

Comment: @ thefourtheye, yes I tried that and it does work but I wanted to use 'this' or just the method name if possible for consistency.

Comment: `get_cp_span().hide()` is not the same as `cp_span.hide()`. Did you try `cp_span.hide()`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ thefourtheye your suggestion does work just fine but I was really surprised not to be able to call 'this.get_cp_span().hide()' or just get_cp_span().  But if there is no alternative, I'll do it like you suggested.

Comment: caroline beltran what you did here makes no sense, thats why you got downvoted twice.

Comment: @Neta Meta, I just wanted to use 'this.get_cp_span()' from within the same function since it is common to do so in other languages but I guess that it is not the case in javascript.  I will just have to reference the var cp_span.

Comment: @Jackson, it is just a variable to reference a span.  I created a getter called this.get_cp_span to reference it from other functions but it appears that I cannot call that getter from within my_namespace() function and I have to reference the var instead.

Comment: I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this if you want to understand how `this` works. *"I was really surprised not to be able to call 'this.get_cp_span().hide()' or just get_cp_span()."* Well, a variable `get_cp_span` doesn't exist, so `get_cp_span()` can't work. `this.get_cp_span().hide()` will work if you call `do_something` "correctly", meaning that its `this` references the correct value. Since you are not showing how and where you are calling `do_something`, there is not much we can say about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new` creates a plain object, inside `my_namespace` `this` points to the newly created object, you can save this object inside another private variable so that any function declared inside `my_namespace` have access to it, I've seen that this variable is commonly named as `self` or `me` but you can name it whatever you want

```
var my_ns;  // global access

$(document).ready(function() {
  my_ns = new my_namespace();   // need global access to my_ns
});

function my_namespace() {
  // save the newly created object
  var me = this;
  var cp_span = $("#cp_span");

  // public getter  
  this.**get_cp_span** = function() {
    return cp_span;
  }

  var do_something = function() {
    me.get_cp_span().hide();
  }
};
```

Note that if you call `my_namespace` multiple times, `me` will refer to each `instance` created, I'd avoid using `new` though since I think that the namespace should be unique right? I'd be better to use the singleton pattern

Comment: I took your advice and used 'self' to reference the outer function from within the inner function which gives me access to the outer method that I needed access to.  Thank you.